# Using Ajax jquery to get data from server

Tags: jquery

I have only recently started looking into Ajax and Jquery. Could somebody help me with this?

I have a list box, upon selection of one item i would like to retrieve the json object associated with it from couchdb using ajax and jquery.I assume I have to use either $.get or $.getJSON.

Where am i supposed to make the connection to couchdb. And, how to append the data to the same page. I am working on ruby.

Could somebody please post a snippet or direct me to an example that would do it.

Answer (score 0):

> Where am i supposed to make the connection to couchdb

You don't. You have to connect to a web providing the service. jQuery only provides page retrieval.

> And, how to append the data to the same page

Just manipulate the DOM.

jQuery documentation has enough examples to learn from.